vscode does not run code properly when using zsh as external terminal
I'm using cmake+clangd+codelldb as a toolchain, and I've set up output to an external terminal in launch.json, but it's not popping up the zsh terminal window properly.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/${workspaceFolderBasename}",
            "terminal": "external",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

When I run debug, it gets stuck at this screen without any external terminal popping up.
debug
But there is indeed a codelldb process running in the background。codelldb
I set the external terminal to zsh in the setting.json，but it also make no sense. But it works fine when I set it to xterm.
xterm &&
run
